# Background color behind selected li

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code below for an a-z index I am creating. Is it possible to have it so whenever a user clicks on a letter the background color from the hover stays behind the selected letter so it shows what letter they chose. Anything helps, cheers.

```js
function letterChange() {
  var panelId = 'panel' + this.innerText;
  var panels = document.querySelectorAll('.js-div');
  [].forEach.call(panels, function(e) {
    if (e.id == panelId)
       e.style.display = "block";
    else
       e.style.display = "none";
  });     
}

// Add click event listener
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.flip');
[].forEach.call(lis, function(e) {
  e.addEventListener("click", letterChange);
});
```

```css
.alphabet {
list-style-type: none;
    margin:0px auto 0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.alphabet li {
float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-right:1px solid darkgrey;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:3.84%;
}

.alphabet li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.alphabet li:hover {
  color: #005bab;
  background-color: #e2ecf6;
}

.bottombar1{
       content: "";
       display:block;
       height:0.7em;
       width:100%;
       background-color:#00688B;
}

#panelA,#panelB,#panelC,#panelD,#panelE,#panelF,#panelG,#panelH,
#panelI,#panelJ,#panelK,#panelL,#panelM,#panelN,#panelO,#panelP,
#panelQ,#panelR,#panelS,#panelT,#panelU,#panelV,#panelW,#panelX,
#panelY,#panelZ {
  display: none;
}

#panelA,#panelB,#panelC,#panelD,#panelE,#panelF,#panelG,#panelH,
#panelI,#panelJ,#panelK,#panelL,#panelM,#panelN,#panelO,#panelP,
#panelQ,#panelR,#panelS,#panelT,#panelU,#panelV,#panelW,#panelX,
#panelY,#panelZ {
    display: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#e2ecf6;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-color:transparent;
    color: #005bab;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="alphabet">
    <li class="flip">A</li>
    <li class="flip">B</li>
    <li class="flip">C</li>
    <li class="flip">D</li>
    <li class="flip">E</li>
    <li class="flip">F</li>
    <li class="flip">G</li>
    <li class="flip">H</li>
    <li class="flip">I</li>
    <li class="flip">J</li>
    <li class="flip">K</li>
    <li class="flip">L</li>
    <li class="flip">M</li>
    <li class="flip">N</li>
    <li class="flip">O</li>
    <li class="flip">P</li>
    <li class="flip">Q</li>
    <li class="flip">R</li>
    <li class="flip">S</li>
    <li class="flip">T</li>
    <li class="flip">U</li>
    <li class="flip">V</li>
    <li class="flip">W</li>
    <li class="flip">X</li>
    <li class="flip">Y</li>
    <li class="flip">Z</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br style="line-height:25px;"/>
<div id="panelA" class="js-div">
  <p>A</p>
</div>
<div id="panelB" class="js-div">
  <p>B</p>
</div>
<div id="panelC" class="js-div">
  <p>C</p>
</div>
<div id="panelD" class="js-div">
  <p>D</p>
</div>
<div id="panelE" class="js-div">
  <p>E</p>
</div>
<div id="panelF" class="js-div">
  <p>F</p>
</div>
<div id="panelG" class="js-div">
  <p>G</p>
</div>
<div id="panelH" class="js-div">
  <p>H</p>
</div>
<div id="panelI" class="js-div">
  <p>I</p>
</div>
<div id="panelJ" class="js-div">
  <p>J</p>
</div>
<div id="panelK" class="js-div">
  <p>K</p>
</div>
<div id="panelL" class="js-div">
  <p>L</p>
</div>
<div id="panelM" class="js-div">
  <p>M</p>
</div>
<div id="panelN" class="js-div">
  <p>N</p>
</div>
<div id="panelO" class="js-div">
  <p>O</p>
</div>
<div id="panelP" class="js-div">
  <p>P</p>
</div>
<div id="panelQ" class="js-div">
  <p>Q</p>
</div>
<div id="panelR" class="js-div">
  <p>R</p>
</div>
<div id="panelS" class="js-div">
  <p>S</p>
</div>
<div id="panelT" class="js-div">
  <p>T</p>
</div>
<div id="panelU" class="js-div">
  <p>U</p>
</div>
<div id="panelV" class="js-div">
  <p>V</p>
</div>
<div id="panelW" class="js-div">
  <p>W</p>
</div>
<div id="panelX" class="js-div">
  <p>X</p>
</div>
<div id="panelY" class="js-div">
  <p>Y</p>
</div>
<div id="panelZ" class="js-div">
  <p>Z</p>
</div>
<div class="bottombar1"></div>
```

Comment: Add and remove a class to the li Elements (example: ´active´) and style the selector as the Same as the hover

Comment: Yes it is, but since the "li" have no hover state, you need to dynamically affect/remove a class to the clicked one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the select letter and apply the background color.Also remove that class when clicking on the next letter

```js
function letterChange() {
  var prevSelected = document.getElementsByClassName("flip selected");
  
  if(prevSelected.length > 0){
     prevSelected[0].classList.remove("selected")
  }
/*  for(var i=0; i< letters.length;i++){
     letters[i].classList.remove("selected");
  }*/
  
  this.className += ' selected';
  var panelId = 'panel' + this.innerText;
  var panels = document.querySelectorAll('.js-div');
  [].forEach.call(panels, function(e) {
    if (e.id == panelId)
       e.style.display = "block";
    else
       e.style.display = "none";
  });     
}

// Add click event listener
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.flip');
[].forEach.call(lis, function(e) {
  e.addEventListener("click", letterChange);
});
```

```css
.alphabet {
list-style-type: none;
    margin:0px auto 0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.alphabet li {
float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-right:1px solid darkgrey;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:3.84%;
}

.alphabet li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.alphabet li:hover ,.selected{
  color: #005bab;
  background-color: #e2ecf6;
}

.bottombar1{
       content: "";
       display:block;
       height:0.7em;
       width:100%;
       background-color:#00688B;
}

#panelA,#panelB,#panelC,#panelD,#panelE,#panelF,#panelG,#panelH,
#panelI,#panelJ,#panelK,#panelL,#panelM,#panelN,#panelO,#panelP,
#panelQ,#panelR,#panelS,#panelT,#panelU,#panelV,#panelW,#panelX,
#panelY,#panelZ {
  display: none;
}

#panelA,#panelB,#panelC,#panelD,#panelE,#panelF,#panelG,#panelH,
#panelI,#panelJ,#panelK,#panelL,#panelM,#panelN,#panelO,#panelP,
#panelQ,#panelR,#panelS,#panelT,#panelU,#panelV,#panelW,#panelX,
#panelY,#panelZ {
    display: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#e2ecf6;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-color:transparent;
    color: #005bab;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="alphabet">
    <li class="flip">A</li>
    <li class="flip">B</li>
    <li class="flip">C</li>
    <li class="flip">D</li>
    <li class="flip">E</li>
    <li class="flip">F</li>
    <li class="flip">G</li>
    <li class="flip">H</li>
    <li class="flip">I</li>
    <li class="flip">J</li>
    <li class="flip">K</li>
    <li class="flip">L</li>
    <li class="flip">M</li>
    <li class="flip">N</li>
    <li class="flip">O</li>
    <li class="flip">P</li>
    <li class="flip">Q</li>
    <li class="flip">R</li>
    <li class="flip">S</li>
    <li class="flip">T</li>
    <li class="flip">U</li>
    <li class="flip">V</li>
    <li class="flip">W</li>
    <li class="flip">X</li>
    <li class="flip">Y</li>
    <li class="flip">Z</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br style="line-height:25px;"/>
<div id="panelA" class="js-div">
  <p>A</p>
</div>
<div id="panelB" class="js-div">
  <p>B</p>
</div>
<div id="panelC" class="js-div">
  <p>C</p>
</div>
<div id="panelD" class="js-div">
  <p>D</p>
</div>
<div id="panelE" class="js-div">
  <p>E</p>
</div>
<div id="panelF" class="js-div">
  <p>F</p>
</div>
<div id="panelG" class="js-div">
  <p>G</p>
</div>
<div id="panelH" class="js-div">
  <p>H</p>
</div>
<div id="panelI" class="js-div">
  <p>I</p>
</div>
<div id="panelJ" class="js-div">
  <p>J</p>
</div>
<div id="panelK" class="js-div">
  <p>K</p>
</div>
<div id="panelL" class="js-div">
  <p>L</p>
</div>
<div id="panelM" class="js-div">
  <p>M</p>
</div>
<div id="panelN" class="js-div">
  <p>N</p>
</div>
<div id="panelO" class="js-div">
  <p>O</p>
</div>
<div id="panelP" class="js-div">
  <p>P</p>
</div>
<div id="panelQ" class="js-div">
  <p>Q</p>
</div>
<div id="panelR" class="js-div">
  <p>R</p>
</div>
<div id="panelS" class="js-div">
  <p>S</p>
</div>
<div id="panelT" class="js-div">
  <p>T</p>
</div>
<div id="panelU" class="js-div">
  <p>U</p>
</div>
<div id="panelV" class="js-div">
  <p>V</p>
</div>
<div id="panelW" class="js-div">
  <p>W</p>
</div>
<div id="panelX" class="js-div">
  <p>X</p>
</div>
<div id="panelY" class="js-div">
  <p>Y</p>
</div>
<div id="panelZ" class="js-div">
  <p>Z</p>
</div>
<div class="bottombar1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a `tabindex` attribute to your `li`'s and set a `:focus` rule in your css.

```js
function letterChange() {
  var panelId = 'panel' + this.innerText;
  var panels = document.querySelectorAll('.js-div');
  [].forEach.call(panels, function(e) {
    if (e.id == panelId)
       e.style.display = "block";
    else
       e.style.display = "none";
  });     
}

// Add click event listener
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.flip');
[].forEach.call(lis, function(e) {
  e.addEventListener("click", letterChange);
});
```

```css
.alphabet {
list-style-type: none;
    margin:0px auto 0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.alphabet li {
float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-right:1px solid darkgrey;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:3.84%;
}

.alphabet li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.alphabet li:hover,
.alphabet li:focus {
  color: #005bab;
  background-color: #e2ecf6;
}

.bottombar1{
       content: "";
       display:block;
       height:0.7em;
       width:100%;
       background-color:#00688B;
}

#panelA,#panelB,#panelC,#panelD,#panelE,#panelF,#panelG,#panelH,
#panelI,#panelJ,#panelK,#panelL,#panelM,#panelN,#panelO,#panelP,
#panelQ,#panelR,#panelS,#panelT,#panelU,#panelV,#panelW,#panelX,
#panelY,#panelZ {
  display: none;
}

#panelA,#panelB,#panelC,#panelD,#panelE,#panelF,#panelG,#panelH,
#panelI,#panelJ,#panelK,#panelL,#panelM,#panelN,#panelO,#panelP,
#panelQ,#panelR,#panelS,#panelT,#panelU,#panelV,#panelW,#panelX,
#panelY,#panelZ {
    display: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#e2ecf6;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-color:transparent;
    color: #005bab;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="alphabet">
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">A</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">B</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">C</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">D</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">E</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">F</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">G</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">H</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">I</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">J</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">K</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">L</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">M</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">N</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">O</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">P</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">Q</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">R</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">S</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">T</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">U</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">V</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">W</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">X</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">Y</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="flip">Z</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br style="line-height:25px;"/>
<div id="panelA" class="js-div">
  <p>A</p>
</div>
<div id="panelB" class="js-div">
  <p>B</p>
</div>
<div id="panelC" class="js-div">
  <p>C</p>
</div>
<div id="panelD" class="js-div">
  <p>D</p>
</div>
<div id="panelE" class="js-div">
  <p>E</p>
</div>
<div id="panelF" class="js-div">
  <p>F</p>
</div>
<div id="panelG" class="js-div">
  <p>G</p>
</div>
<div id="panelH" class="js-div">
  <p>H</p>
</div>
<div id="panelI" class="js-div">
  <p>I</p>
</div>
<div id="panelJ" class="js-div">
  <p>J</p>
</div>
<div id="panelK" class="js-div">
  <p>K</p>
</div>
<div id="panelL" class="js-div">
  <p>L</p>
</div>
<div id="panelM" class="js-div">
  <p>M</p>
</div>
<div id="panelN" class="js-div">
  <p>N</p>
</div>
<div id="panelO" class="js-div">
  <p>O</p>
</div>
<div id="panelP" class="js-div">
  <p>P</p>
</div>
<div id="panelQ" class="js-div">
  <p>Q</p>
</div>
<div id="panelR" class="js-div">
  <p>R</p>
</div>
<div id="panelS" class="js-div">
  <p>S</p>
</div>
<div id="panelT" class="js-div">
  <p>T</p>
</div>
<div id="panelU" class="js-div">
  <p>U</p>
</div>
<div id="panelV" class="js-div">
  <p>V</p>
</div>
<div id="panelW" class="js-div">
  <p>W</p>
</div>
<div id="panelX" class="js-div">
  <p>X</p>
</div>
<div id="panelY" class="js-div">
  <p>Y</p>
</div>
<div id="panelZ" class="js-div">
  <p>Z</p>
</div>
<div class="bottombar1"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't want to go this way, because when you click somewhere else on the page, the background disappears.